# Error [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.7.0-alpine: Service 'web' failed to build

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

when ever i run this docker-compose --env-file .env.dev build command it's show the  Error [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.7.0-alpine:    Service 'web' failed to build

Comment: Are there any more error messages?  Can you provide a [mcve]?  What's the host operating system and architecture?

Comment: Can you post the docker compose YAML you are targeting? Even if proprietary names need to be obfuscated, this would be very helpful.